# Keeping track of braces and brackets { } [ ]

Tags: syntax

It doesn't take much to end up with lots of braces, i.e, { or }, and brackets, i.e., [ or ], in even a single line of MM code, and it's very easy to lose track of how many there are and *where* they should be.  I have spent hours trying to find where I left one out or added an extra unneeded one.  Does anybody have an automated way to keep track of whether they are balanced or not?  Some kind of automated way would be best but...Would color coding them help?  Would structuring code with indentations help? Maybe I just need to understand them and their associated error indications better.
Thanks

Comment: You can double-triple-quadruple-… click to select more and more and easily spot it. If you have that many braces, it is probably a good idea to spread it over multiple lines, either a single expression with new lines in there, or multiple expressions on separate lines.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? There is syntax highlighting in newer versions, so you put the cursor next to the brace, and the matching one gets the same color, see [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTIEO.png). Also, if you go to Palettes > Code Formatting, you have the tools to format the structure of the code.

Comment: I'm using veraion 13.2.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Another idea is to make more use of @, e.g., `foo @ bar @ stuff`

Comment: The "double-triple-quadruple-… click" is accessible also via CTRL-period. I use it so much that I have it mapped to one of my trackball buttons. Also using operators chained by `//` can reduce the number of brackets.